# How to write a file with Jenkins http_request plugin in gzip format?

Tags: linux, jenkins, download, jenkins-pipeline, gzip

In a JenkinsFile, I am trying to recover a gzip compressed file from the url: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases/download/v1.91.0/pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz.

With the command

> sh 'curl -LO
> [https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases/download/v1.91.0/pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz'](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases/download/v1.91.0/pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz%27)

things work neatly and I can unzip the file etc. However, I need to make this http request via the http_request plugin from Jenkins (doc here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request)

My code follows the Jenkins documentation:

```
def response = httpRequest url: "https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases/download/v1.91.0/pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz",
                                                httpMode: 'GET'
writeFile file: 'pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz', text: response.content
```

The issue is that it does not recognize the file as a gzip compressed data, so I cannot really unzip it via the command `tar xzf pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`.

To check for the file format, I ran the following command in the JenkinsFile:

`sh 'file pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz'`

Output: pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz: **data**

Output Expected: pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz: **gzip compressed data**

I tried to see if I could get the original file and change its format via a linux command, but not sure this is possible. Maybe there is a way either from Jenkins or from Linux to convert this file to a gzip format?

Comment: It is possible that the gzip file is being automatically decompressed as part of the HTTP transfer. Have you checked to see whether or not what you have downloaded is the decompressed .tar file?

Comment: Hi @MarkAdler, indeed I did. I put a ls command to debug it and it did not list the expected folders if the the file were already decompressed

Comment: You would check with `tar xf`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MarkAdler. The tar xf did work either. There is something about the writeFile that converts it to the generic format data I cannot quite understand how to work properly. In all cases, using the solution in my answer makes the appropriate conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I was able to find another solution by using the outputFile parameter provided by the Jenkins plugin as the following:

```
httpRequest url: "https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases/download/v1.91.0/pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz",
                                                    httpMode: 'GET',
                                                    validResponseCodes: "200"
                                                    outputFile: 'pact-1.91.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz'
```